# Swift: Changing (translate) a UIView position through a pan gesture in its superview window

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

## Introduction

**Context:**

In my main ViewController I have a scrollView with a few objects inside (which are UIViews). When one of the UIViews are tapped/selected I animate forward a UITextView in a UIView to go with the selected object. (only one UIView can appear at a time)

This UIView that appears on object selection is separated into a separate class called `AdjunctiveTextView`.

**Issue/goal:**

(the example code provided below will clear make this clear, I've also commented where the issue lies in the code)

When an object has been tapped and has an adjacent UIView with a text I want to have that adjacent UIView to follow with the scrollView.

- I'm using a UIPanGestureRecognizer to attempt to do this. But I can't figure out how to make it work when the user drags in the scrollview. It only work if the user drags on the actual adjunctiveTextView.
- Everything works as expected except that the adjunctiveTextView does not change its position during the panGesture.
- I would like (if possible) to have the AdjunctiveTextView as a separate class. My ViewController file is getting rather big.

**Question:**

Why doesn't the UIPanGestureRecognizer work as expected? What is needed in order for it to translate the backView correctly?

## Code

**My attempt: (as shown below)**

My attempt simply makes the backView itself "dragable" around through the panGesture. Nothing happens to it when I scroll the scrollView.

(I have only included relevant portions of my code)

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let adjunctiveTextView = AdjunctiveTextView()

    // this is a delegate method which gets called when an object is tapped in the scrollView
    func scrollViewObjectIsTapped(_ objectScrollView: ObjectScrollView, object: AvailableObject) {

   **   adjunctiveTextView.scrollView = scrollView // **Edited! (scrollView is the name of the scrollView in this class too)
        adjunctiveTextView.showView(passInObject: AvailableObject)
    }

}

class AdjunctiveTextView: NSObject {
     lazy var backView: UIView = {
         //backView setup
     }
     lazy var textView: UITextView = {
         //textView setup
     }

      //additional init and setup
 **  weak var scrollView : UIScrollView! // **Edited!
     func showView(passInObject: AvailableObject) {
         if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {

             // the issue must either be here in the PanGesture setup
             let panG = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(translateView(sender:)))
             panG.cancelsTouchesInView = false
            // window.addGestureRecognizer(panG) 
       **    scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(panG) // **Edited!
             window.addSubview(backView)

             textView.text = passInObject.information
             backView.frame = CGRect(x: passInObject.frame.minX, y: passInObject.minY, width: window.frame.width - passInObject.maxX - 6, height: textView.bounds.height + 5)
             backView.alpha = 0

             //it animates a change of the backViews x position and alpha.
             UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.42, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
                 self.backView.alpha = 1
                 self.backView.frame = CGRect(x: passInObject.frame.minX + passInObject.frame.width, y: passInObject.minY, width: window.frame.width - passInObject.maxX - 6, height: textView.bounds.height + 5)

             }, completion: nil)
         }
     }

     // or the issue is here in the handle function for the PanGesture.
     @objc private func translateView(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

          if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
             let translation = sender.translation(in: window)  //Have tried setting this to scrollView also
             switch sender.state {
             case .began, .changed:
                 backView.center = CGPoint(x: backView.center.x, y: backView.center.y + translation.y)
                 sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: window) //Have tried setting this to sccrollView also
                 break
             case .ended:
                 break
             default:
                 break
             }

         }
     }


}
```

Thanks for reading my question.

Answer (score 0):

I just add a weak reference to your scrollView and then add the pan gesture to scrollView. It works as you want. You may consider add another pan gesture to the back view if you want your original behavior.

```
class AdjunctiveTextView: NSObject {
lazy var backView: UIView = {
    //backView setup
 return UIView.init()
}()
lazy var textView: UITextView = {
    //textView setup
return UITextView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 100))
}()

weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

//additional init and setup

func showView(passInObject: AvailableObject) {
    if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {

        // the issue must either be here in the PanGesture setup
        let panG = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(translateView(sender:)))
        panG.cancelsTouchesInView = false
      //  passInObject.addGestureRecognizer(panG)

 scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(panG)

        window.addSubview(backView)

        textView.text = passInObject.information
        textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        backView.addSubview(textView)

        backView.frame = CGRect(x: passInObject.frame.minX, y: passInObject.frame.minY, width: window.frame.width - passInObject.frame.maxX - 6, height: textView.bounds.height + 5)
        backView.alpha = 0

        //it animates a change of the backViews x position and alpha.
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.42, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            self.backView.alpha = 1
            self.backView.frame = CGRect(x: passInObject.frame.minX + passInObject.frame.width , y: passInObject.frame.minY , width: window.frame.width - passInObject.frame.maxX - 6, height: self.textView.bounds.height + 5)

           self.backView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

        }, completion: nil)
    }
}

// or the issue is here in the handle function for the PanGesture.
@objc private func translateView(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
        let translation = sender.translation(in: window)
        switch sender.state {
        case .began, .changed:
            backView.center = CGPoint(x: backView.center.x, y: backView.center.y + translation.y)
            sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: window)
            break
        case .ended:
            break
        default:
            break
        }

    }
   }
}


  class ObjectScrollView: UIScrollView{
  }

 class AvailableObject: UIView{
  var information: String!
 }

 class MySCNViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var oScrollView: ObjectScrollView!

// this is a delegate method which gets called when an object is tapped in the scrollView
  func scrollViewObjectIsTapped(_ objectScrollView: ObjectScrollView, object: AvailableObject) {
    adjunctiveTextView.showView(passInObject: object)
  }

  let  adjunctiveTextView = AdjunctiveTextView()
  let ao =   AvailableObject.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200))

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
     ao.information = "test"
    adjunctiveTextView.scrollView = oScrollView
      ao.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow
   }

     @IBAction  func tap(_ sender: Any?){
             scrollViewObjectIsTapped(oScrollView, object: ao)}
   }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I tried writing that out as you suggested, but it does not work, nothing happens to the backViews position when I scroll the scrollView. I edited my question with ** marks where the changes are. Am I missing something? Would appreciate if you could take a quick look.

Comment: I update with complete code. You can directly run it without any modification.